# Reformatting TexMemo into Spanish

Tags: templates, document-classes, languages, optional-arguments, class-options

So I dowloaded a memo template from ShareLatex, the TexMemo. Essentially, I want to reformat the entire template into Spanish. Additionally, I want the fields at the top to be written in spanish. For instance, for the memo heading I want

To: --> Para:
From: --> De:
Subject: --> Asunto:
Date: --> Fecha:

I am pretty sure that the issue lies with the .cls file. I managed to insert the \Requirepackage[spanish]{babel} line without error, but it does not change the memo heading into spanish. I think this is because I need to change the redefined commands in the .cls file, though I do not know how to do it. The syntax of this template confuses me. Here's what it looks like:

```
% Specialized memo Commands (To, From, Subject, Logo, Letterhead Address)

\def\@memoto{\relax}
\newcommand{\memoto}[1]{\gdef\@memoto{#1}}

\def\@memofrom{\relax}
\newcommand{\memofrom}[1]{\gdef\@memofrom{#1}}

\def\@memosubject{\relax}
\newcommand{\memosubject}[1]{\gdef\@memosubject{#1}}

\def\@memodate{\relax}
\newcommand{\memodate}[1]{\gdef\@memodate{#1}}

\def\@memologo{\relax}
\newcommand{\logo}[1]{\gdef\@memologo{\protect #1}}

\def\@letterheadaddress{\relax}
\newcommand{\lhaddress}[1]{\gdef\@letterheadaddress{#1}}
```

How may I redefine the commands so that they follow the spanish specifications I outlined above? Would it be under the \newcommand{} or the \gdef{} ?

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace lines 63-69 of the .cls file  with:

```
% To, From, Subject Block
\begin{description}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@memoto}{\relax}}{}{\item [{Para:}] \@memoto}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@memofrom}{\relax}}{}{\item [{De:}] \@memofrom}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@memosubject}{\relax}}{}{\item [{Asunto:}] \@memosubject}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@memodate}{\relax}}{}{\item [{Fecha:}] \@memodate}
\end{description}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently, I had not looked at the .cls carefully. The commands to insert the memo information is at the bottom of the file. I'll be sure to read up on the syntax.

Comment: The commands you've posted are designed to store  the information you give in the preamble until it's used in the body of the document, somewhat like `\author  or `\title` for the `\maketitle` command.